# Binding a FormSet in a ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I'm writing an app for managing health care plans which manages things like Allergies, Diabetes, etc.

I have a form that I can successfully create new records with, but I'm running into problems when it comes to updating that data. My problem is that I'm not sure how to bind my formsets to the saved data when the UpdateView is opened. My current strategy is to follow the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197194/django-modelformset-factory-filtering/17204434#17204434), but I'm not sure if it's the right one in this context.

Right now, when I try to go to the `PlanUpdateView` url, I get the following error on `medication_form_set = MedicationFormSet()(queryset=medication_queryset)`:

```
builtins.TypeError
TypeError: 'MedicationFormFormSet' object is not callable
```

### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

from .models import Allergy, Medication, Allergen


class AllergyPlanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Allergy
        widgets = {
            'asthma': forms.RadioSelect,
            'allow_carry': forms.RadioSelect,
            'self_carry_admin': forms.RadioSelect,
        }
        fields = ('asthma', 'allow_carry', 'self_carry_admin', 'hc_provide_sign', 'par_provide_sign')


MedicationFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Allergy, Medication,
                                          fields=('dose', 'med_type', 'name_brand', 'side_effects'),
                                          extra=1)
AllergenFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Allergy, Allergen,
                                        fields=('allergen', 'insect_stings', 'other_text'),
                                        extra=1,)
```

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Allergy(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey('powerschool_schema.Student', db_column='studentsdcid')
    asthma = models.BooleanField(choices=(
        (True, 'Yes (if yes, high risk for severe reaction, please also complete IHP101.1 form)'),
        (False, 'No'),
    ), default='Unspecified')
    allow_carry = models.BooleanField(choices=(
        (True, 'It is medically appropriate for the student to self-carry Epinephrine Auto Injector (EAI) medication.'),
        (False, 'It is not medically appropriate to carray and self-administer this EAI medication.')
    ), default='Unspecified')
    self_carry_admin = models.BooleanField(choices=(
        (True, 'Student can self-carry and self-administer EAI if needed, when able and appropriate.'),
        (False, 'Student can self-carry, but not self-administer EAI.')
    ), default='Unspecified')
    hc_provide_sign = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Healthcare Provider Signature Provided')
    par_provide_sign = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Parent Signature Provided')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('health-care-plan:update', kwargs={
            'student_dcid': self.student.dcid,
            'plan_type': self._meta.verbose_name,
            'plan_id': self.id})

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'U_ALLERGY'
        verbose_name = 'allergy'
        verbose_name_plural = 'allergies'


class Medication(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    allergy = models.ForeignKey(Allergy, db_column='u_allergyid')
    dose = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    med_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name_brand = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    side_effects = models.CharField(max_length=4000)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'U_MEDICATION'


class Allergen(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    allergy = models.ForeignKey(Allergy, db_column='u_allergyid')
    allergen = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    insect_stings = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    other_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'U_ALLERGEN'
```

### views.py

```
class PlanUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'health_care_plan/plan-create.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        allergy = get_object_or_404(Allergy, id=self.kwargs.get('plan_id'))
        form = self.get_form_class(allergy)
        medication_queryset = Medication.objects.filter(allergy=allergy)
        medication_form_set = MedicationFormSet()(queryset=medication_queryset)
        allergen_queryset = Allergen.objects.filter(allergy=allergy)
        allergen_form_set = AllergenFormSet()(queryset=allergen_queryset)

        student_dcid = self.kwargs.get('student_dcid')
        student = get_object_or_404(Student, dcid=student_dcid)
        plan_type = self.kwargs.get('plan_type')

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(student=student,
                                  plan_type=plan_type,
                                  form=form,
                                  medication_form_set=medication_form_set,
                                  allergen_form_set=allergen_form_set))

    def get_form_class(self, plan_object):
        plan_type = self.kwargs.get('plan_type')
        if plan_type == 'allergy':
            return AllergyPlanForm(instance=plan_object)

    def get_queryset(self):
        plan_type = self.kwargs.get('plan_type')
        if plan_type == 'allergy':
            return Allergy.objects.all()
```

### EDIT

Changing my view code from

```
medication_queryset = Medication.objects.filter(allergy=allergy)
medication_form_set = MedicationFormSet()(queryset=medication_queryset)

allergen_queryset = Allergen.objects.filter(allergy=allergy)
allergen_form_set = AllergenFormSet()(queryset=allergen_queryset)
```

to

```
medication_queryset = Medication.objects.filter(allergy=allergy)
medication_form_set = MedicationFormSet(queryset=medication_queryset)

allergen_queryset = Allergen.objects.filter(allergy=allergy)
allergen_form_set = AllergenFormSet(queryset=allergen_queryset)
```

now gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'PlanUpdateView' object has no attribute 'object'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 53, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/powerschool_apps/health_care_plan/views.py", line 142, in get
    allergen_form_set=allergen_form_set))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 94, in get_context_data
    return super(FormMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 101, in get_context_data
    if self.object:
AttributeError: 'PlanUpdateView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alasdair's suggestion helped, but what also helped was to assign `self.object` to the object that I was trying to bind the form with.

```
class PlanUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'health_care_plan/plan-create.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = get_object_or_404(Allergy, id=self.kwargs.get('plan_id'))
        plan_type = self.kwargs.get('plan_type')
        form = self.get_form_class(self.object)
        medication_form_set = MedicationFormSet(instance=self.object)
        allergen_form_set = AllergenFormSet(instance=self.object)

        student_dcid = self.kwargs.get('student_dcid')
        student = get_object_or_404(Student, dcid=student_dcid)

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(student=student,
                                  plan_type=plan_type,
                                  form=form,
                                  medication_form_set=medication_form_set,
                                  allergen_form_set=allergen_form_set))

    def get_form_class(self, plan_object):
        plan_type = self.kwargs.get('plan_type')
        if plan_type == 'allergy':
            return AllergyPlanForm(instance=plan_object)

    def get_queryset(self):
        plan_type = self.kwargs.get('plan_type')
        if plan_type == 'allergy':
            return Allergy.objects.all()

    def get_success_url(self):
        reverse('health-care-plan:index', kwargs={'students_dcid': self.kwargs.get('student_dcid')})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this problem today, and I used `model_to_dict`. Here's my code:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    profile = ClientProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileSubmissionForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('jobs:list'))
    else:
        profile_dict = model_to_dict(profile)
        form = ProfileSubmissionForm(profile_dict)
        return render(request, 'jobs/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Notice that I'm passing the `profile` to the `model_to_dict`.

Does this help?